# Finding the fundamental frequency of .wav file in java

Tags: java, matlab, signal-processing, fft, phoneme

I have a project to complete which requires me to find the fundamental frequencies of phoneme vowels of human voice. I am new to sound processing and don't know how to proceed with this. Can anyone guide me how I should approach this problem?

I have tried searching methods for finding the fundamental frequency using FFT and Auto-correlation methods but I'm unable to find a solution. Can anyone provide me with a code snippet?

Comment: I have no idea what you tried to search in the internet, but if you google it correctly you will find everything you need: [google result](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&client=firefox-b&ei=hjDPWoTiL8fe6QSi5a6ADg&q=Fundamental+frequency+audio+processing&oq=Fundamental+frequency+audio+processing&gs_l=psy-ab.3...6500.6500.0.7940.1.1.0.0.0.0.100.100.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.h6ZdWYRldCY)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting the fundamental frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435533/detecting-the-fundamental-frequency)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the RAPT is the best algorithm of pitch tracking.

See the [algorithm description](https://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/papers/Talkin95-rapt.pdf).

I have used two RAPT implementations:

- The [Speech Filing System](https://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/resource/sfs/). With google you can also find sources. This is very good reference implementation in pure C. Unfortunately integrating this to some system is not very trivial.
- The [VOICEBOX](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/voicebox/doc/voicebox/fxrapt.html) MATLAB implementation. Sometimes gives other results compared with the previous algorithm implementation.

N.B. If you need the precise pitch frequency estimation you have to look at the [Instantaneous RAPT algorithm](http://dsp.tut.su/irapt.html).